# One product with multiple instances and sell each instance once

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress and Woocommerce to make an online store. I want to sell some accounts (username and password). For example, the product name would be "Foo" and contains 100 files each containing an account information. So, the product should appear once in store and on each sale one file should be delivered to user. How can I do this? Is there any add-on for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to be looking at "Digital Downloads". For example a rough overview on this is here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digital-downloadable-product-handling/

And then to create the "different" files you will use product "Variations", where each variation would be a file.